# I want to apply alignment to ranges of cells using openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am getting a typeError that a cell object is not iterable. I understand that I cannot iterate over objects but my confusion is what am I supposed to be iterating over to define alignment of the cells. here is my code:

```
def File_formatting():
    wb = load_workbook(filename=output_file_path)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws['B3'] = 'ERSC/VFD/OL configured'
    ws.merge_cells('B2:B3')
    ws['C3'] = 'Motor/VFD/Disc Faults'
    ws.merge_cells('C3:D3')
    ws['E3'] = 'Horns'
    ws.merge_cells('E3:F3')
    ws['G3'] = 'Runs'
    ws.merge_cells('G3:H3')
    ws['I3'] = 'ESTOPS'
    ws.merge_cells('I3:J3')
    ws['K3'] = 'Full(s)'
    ws.merge_cells('K3:L3')
    ws['M3'] = 'Implied Case Jam(s)'
    ws.merge_cells('M3:N3')
    ws['O3'] = 'Jam(s)'
    ws.merge_cells('O3:P3')
    ws['Q3']= 'Beacon Lights'
    ws.merge_cells('Q3:R3')
    ws['S3'] = 'Solenoids'
    ws.merge_cells('S3:T3')
    ws['U3']= 'misc Items'
    ws.merge_cells('U3:V3')
    ws['W3'] = 'Cascade'
    ws.merge_cells('W3:X3')
    ws['Y3']= 'Up/Down Conv ILKs'
    ws.merge_cells('Y3:Z3')
    ws['AA2'] = 'Final Sign Off'
    ws.merge_cells('AA2:AB2')
    ws['AA3'] = 'Test Date'
    ws['AB3'] = 'Engineer Initials'
    ws['AC1'] = '="Functional Check % Completion: " & TEXT( COUNTIF(AA4:AA149, ">1/1/1900")/COUNTA(A4:A149),"0.0%")'
    ws['A1'] = 'Put Checksheet name here'
    ws.merge_cells('A1:AB1')
    ws['C2'] = 'Operational Checkout'
    ws.merge_cells('C2:Z2')
    cell_ranges = ['B2:B3', 'C3:D3', 'E3:F3', 'G3:H3', 'I3:J3', 'K3:L3', 'M3:N3', 'O3:P3', 'Q3:R3',
                   'S3:T3', 'U3:V3', 'W3:X3', 'Y3:Z3', 'AA2:AB2', 'AA3:AB3', 'AC1']

    # Set alignment for specified cell ranges
    blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='0000FF', end_color='0000FF', fill_type='solid')
    for cell_range in cell_ranges:
        for row in ws[cell_range]:
            for cell in row:
                cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='bottom')
                cell.fill = blue_fill
    wb.save(filename=output_file_path)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am expecting to just use this function to output a specific base format for an excel file and I would like to do the highlighting for the user of the function for them before they even open it up.

Comment: Seems you are trying to apply formatting to cells that no longer exist, like in range 'B2:B3', these cells are merged to technically 'B3' no longer exists.

Comment: This is the problem when you try to use cell coordinates, which are supposed to be used interactively, programmatically. Openpyxl detects ranges that are of the same column or row. Use `ws.iter_rows()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment when two or more cells are merged only the top left cell technically still exists in the sheet, while the other merged cells do not.
Therefore it would not be necessary to format those non existent cells and your code could be changed to just format the top left cell, i.e. the list cell_ranges can be changed to the following

```
cell_ranges = ['B2', 'C3', 'E3', 'G3', 'I3', 'K3', 'M3', 'O3', 'Q3', 'S3', 'U3', 'W3', 'Y3', 'AA2', 'AA3', 'AC1']
```

Then just apply to these cells

```
def File_formatting():
    wb = load_workbook(filename=output_file_path)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]

    ws['B3'] = 'ERSC/VFD/OL configured'
    ws.merge_cells('B2:B3')
    ws['C3'] = 'Motor/VFD/Disc Faults'
    ws.merge_cells('C3:D3')
    ws['E3'] = 'Horns'
    ws.merge_cells('E3:F3')
    ws['G3'] = 'Runs'
    ws.merge_cells('G3:H3')
    ws['I3'] = 'ESTOPS'
    ws.merge_cells('I3:J3')
    ws['K3'] = 'Full(s)'
    ws.merge_cells('K3:L3')
    ws['M3'] = 'Implied Case Jam(s)'
    ws.merge_cells('M3:N3')
    ws['O3'] = 'Jam(s)'
    ws.merge_cells('O3:P3')
    ws['Q3']= 'Beacon Lights'
    ws.merge_cells('Q3:R3')
    ws['S3'] = 'Solenoids'
    ws.merge_cells('S3:T3')
    ws['U3']= 'misc Items'
    ws.merge_cells('U3:V3')
    ws['W3'] = 'Cascade'
    ws.merge_cells('W3:X3')
    ws['Y3']= 'Up/Down Conv ILKs'
    ws.merge_cells('Y3:Z3')
    ws['AA2'] = 'Final Sign Off'
    ws.merge_cells('AA2:AB2')
    ws['AA3'] = 'Test Date'
    ws['AB3'] = 'Engineer Initials'
    ws['AC1'] = '="Functional Check % Completion: " & TEXT( COUNTIF(AA4:AA149, ">1/1/1900")/COUNTA(A4:A149),"0.0%")'
    ws['A1'] = 'Put Checksheet name here'
    ws.merge_cells('A1:AB1')
    ws['C2'] = 'Operational Checkout'
    ws.merge_cells('C2:Z2')
    # cell_ranges = ['B2:B3', 'C3:D3', 'E3:F3', 'G3:H3', 'I3:J3', 'K3:L3', 'M3:N3', 'O3:P3', 'Q3:R3',
    #                'S3:T3', 'U3:V3', 'W3:X3', 'Y3:Z3', 'AA2:AB2', 'AA3:AB3', 'AC1']

    cell_ranges = ['B2', 'C3', 'E3', 'G3', 'I3', 'K3', 'M3', 'O3', 'Q3', 'S3', 'U3', 'W3',
                   'Y3', 'AA2', 'AA3', 'Ab3', 'AC1']


    ### Set alignment for specified cell ranges
    blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='0000FF', end_color='0000FF', fill_type='solid')
    # for cell_range in cell_ranges:
    #     for row in ws[cell_range]:
    #         for cell in row:
    #             cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='bottom')
    #             cell.fill = blue_fill

    for cell in cell_ranges:
        ws[cell].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='bottom')
        ws[cell].fill = blue_fill

    wb.save(filename=output_file_path)
```

Maybe a cleaner way to do this is to use a dictionary and set the key as the range and value as the value to be entered and use one loop for everything;

```
blue_fill = PatternFill(start_color='DDEBF7', end_color='DDEBF7', fill_type='solid')


def format_cell(sheet_cell):
    sheet_cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='bottom')
    sheet_cell.fill = blue_fill


def File_formatting(output_file_path):
    wb = load_workbook(filename=output_file_path)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]

    cell_data = {
        'B2:B3': 'ERSC/VFD/OL configured',
        'C3:D3': 'Motor/VFD/Disc Faults',
        'E3:F3': 'Horns',
        'G3:H3': 'Runs',
        'I3:J3': 'ESTOPS',
        'K3:L3': 'Full(s)',
        'M3:N3': 'Implied Case Jam(s)',
        'O3:P3': 'Jam(s)',
        'Q3:R3': 'Beacon Lights',
        'S3:T3': 'Solenoids',
        'U3:V3': 'misc Items',
        'W3:X3': 'Cascade',
        'Y3:Z3': 'Up/Down Conv ILKs',
        'AA2:AB2': 'Final Sign Off',
        'AA3': 'Test Date',
        'AB3': 'Engineer Initials',
        'AC1': '="Functional Check % Completion: " & TEXT( COUNTIF(AA4:AA149, ">1/1/1900")/COUNTA(A4:A149),"0.0%")',
        'A1:AB1': 'Put Checksheet name here',
        'C2:Z2': 'Operational Checkout'
    }

    ### Top left coordinates of cells to be formatted
    formating = ['B2', 'C3', 'E3', 'G3', 'I3', 'K3', 'M3', 'O3', 'Q3', 'S3', 'U3', 'W3',
                 'Y3', 'AA2', 'AA3', 'AB3', 'AC1']

    for cell_range, cell_value in cell_data.items():
        ### Merge cells that are a range of 2 or more cells
        tlc = ws[cell_range]  # tlc is top left cell
        if ':' in cell_range:
            tlc = ws[cell_range.split(':')[0]]
            ws.merge_cells(cell_range)

        tlc.value = cell_value  # Enter Value after cells are merged

        ### If the Top Left Cell coordinate is in the format list then apply the formatting
        if tlc.coordinate in formating:
            format_cell(tlc)

    wb.save(filename=output_file_path)
```

Comment: Ugh! Use CellRange objects if you're going to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much this is what I was looking for! new coder so I'm not too familiar with the ins and outs yet but I'm getting there.